# How to share selector properties amongst x selectors in LESS

Tags: css, less

I have the following situation...

```
    #cat {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 1em;
    font-size:1.2em;
    background:red;
    }

    #dog {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 1em;
    font-size:1.2em;
    background:red;
    }
```

...is there a way in LESS to create a global function that has these properties and shares it upon x selectors like this...

```
(my-pet-basics) {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 1em;
    font-size:1.2em;
    background:red;
}

#cat {
  (my-pet-basics) 
  //..additional unique properties
}

#dog {
  (my-pet-basics) 
  //..additional unique properties
}
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Please go through [the documentation on mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature).

Comment: Thank you so much Harry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is and it's called a mixin. See: http://lesscss.org/features/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you have to look at [Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature). To directly understand your question.

You should write the following **LESS** code:

```
.my-pet-basics() {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 1em;
    font-size:1.2em;
    background:red;
}

#cat {
  .my-pet-basics();
  //..additional unique properties
}

#dog {
  .my-pet-basics();
  //..additional unique properties
}
```

That results in the following **CSS** one:

```
#cat {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 1em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: red;

  //..additional unique properties
}

#dog {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 1em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: red;

  //..additional unique properties
}
```

Adding `()` after mixin name is useful to not have a `.my-pet-basics` class in the final CSS.